# How to change location of the C: drive to the desktop in python 2.4.4

Tags: python, location

I am using python  2.4.4 version to maintain the application there is a license code which searches for licence file in the C-drive but I am facing the issues in detecting the file so I want to change the location of the reading of the generated license file

Can anyone please anyone advise me how to sort it out?

Comment: 1. Your question would more understandable if you would use punctuation marks. 2. What issues do you face exactly? 3. What do you want to change - the location of the license file or the location where this file is being searched?

Comment: So I want change the location to desktop,

Comment: I want to change the location of the code where it searches for the license file.

Comment: my license file is not found either the license file is copied to the 'C:\\' now I want check whether it is working in the location 'C:\users\public\desktop '.

Comment: I want to change both the location of the file to be copied and location of the file to be searched.

Comment: How do you dearch for the file? And what error message do you recieve?

Comment: i have the program like licensing in the application if the license file generated is copied to the specified location it gets the string in the console "file found" else not.

Answer (score 0):

You must:

```
import os
```

and then do:

```
os.chdir("/path/to/change/to")
```

Comment: If this does not work try putting another  backslash(\) on every \ you see like this:

    C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop

Comment: I works for me sorry don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: if i give path like this does it works  ("C:/path/to/change/to")?

Comment: You must put the path to the desktop there. and put another backslash where you see a backslash C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop

Comment: Can  use it with the Self object like example: self.cdrive = os.chdir(C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop)